# Jquery: Unbind event handlers to bind again later

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have to turn off the block and then turn it on again, do so

```
event = $('#left_scroll').data('events');
$('#left_scroll').unbind();
$('#left_scroll').bind(event);
```

does not work, why ?

Comment: What is the value `event`? That's probably the problem.

Comment: The problem is that the `unbind` will remove the handlers from the event variable as well, because it holds a reference to the methods and not copies of the methods..

Comment: Say what? `unbind` shoudn't do anything to the methods declarations it unbinds the event handlers leaving the handler functions intact. @igor  why doesn't it work - do you get any error message? Is the output correct if you try to do `console.log(event);` before the line in which you try to bind this this `event` object to `#left_scroll` ?

Comment: @WTK, we are dealing with objects here.. The `.data('events')` returns an object which holds arrays with the handlers for each event type bound. Storing that to a variable merely holds a reference to that object. `unbind` will remove the handlers from the DOM element which will be reflected to the object in the `.data('events')` and thus on the variable pointing to it(*it will be wiped clean, an empty object*). That is what the OP tries to re-bind later on.. an empty object..

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you're wrong, but netherless I'll check the jQuery source in a sec.

Comment: Yep, you are wrong. The fact that `.data('events')` points to an object doesn't change a thing. Unbind removes "link" between handlers and the event loop, but the handlers are **left as they were**. @igor I've created simple test and it is working so check my question above and elaborate on reasons and symptoms of your code not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It should work as expected, most probably you have an error somewhere else in your code. Check working example here http://jsfiddle.net/VfJhd/4/

Comment: you are binding the events through the `data('events',{..})`.. have a look at the normal binding.. http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/VfJhd/5/ `.data('events') is a special way to access the whole list of bound events.. you are not supposed to abuse it by binding directly to it, unless you know the intrinsic details of what gets included in the data ..

Comment: Use the normal jquery binding methods and check what the `.data('events')` hold and you will see what i mean..

Comment: Gosh, now I understand what was going on. `data('events')` as used by author refers to internal property, an array of events already already binded to the object. That way, you're right, the moment you do `unbind` the internal property gets updated to blank object. The whole time I was assuming that `data('events')` is holding some assigned by author list of events.

Comment: Sry for the mixup. You're however wrong about one thing. Because of how `jQuery.data()` works, using code: `$(obj).data('events', {....})` **isn't** the same as `obj.events = {...}` or even `$(obj).attr('events', {....})`.